# How to restart a Java Application launching a specific class of my application?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I have the following situatation:

I have a Java **Swing** application.

In the class that implement my GUI I have a button named **Log Out** tath is binding to an event listener that handle the click event, something like it:

```
JButton logOutButton = new JButton("LogOut");
header.add(logOutButton);
```

Then in the same class that implement my GUI I have declared the **ActionListener** that handle this event using an inner class:

```
    logOutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("logOutButton clicked !!!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```

In this moment when I click the **logOutButton** button the program end. I would that instead exit it is restarted by running a specific class called **LoginForm** (the class that implement the login form GUI)

What can I do to do this thing?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Why exit at all why not just present the login form again?

Comment: I think that I need to restart my application to lost some settings

Comment: I think you should reorder your code and call something like a reset method to place your application back into a virgin state.

Comment: 1st) Remove System.exit() 2nd) Go Back to LoginForm :) create a new instance or make a resetButton

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to `close/open window` junky approach at all. Just use [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html):

1. set Frame's content pane's layout to  card layout.

   ```
   getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout());
   ```
2. Put your different Form's content code inside different panel and
   add them to the content pane with their corresponding name, for example:

   ```
    getContetnPane().add(logInFormPanel, "logIn Form");
   ```
3. Now you can simulate the card to appear whenever necessary by calling `CardLayout.show(Container parent, String name)`. For example:

   ```
    logOutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                 System.out.println("logOutButton clicked !!!");
             CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(getContentPane().getLayout());
             cl.show(getContentPane(), "logIn Form");

       }
   });
   ```

Check out a [**`CardLayout` demo**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577104/go-back-to-prior-jpanel/19577478#19577478) from my another answer.