# disposing frame from swingWorker

Tags: java, swing, jframe, swingworker

actually i have called the swing worker from a frame (Suppose) A.. in the swing worker class in do-in-Background method i have certain db queries and i am calling frame B too.. in the done() method however i want to dispose the frame A.. how can i do that..? i cannot write dispose() in frame A class because that results in disposing of frame before the new frame(frame B) is visible... Please help!!

```
class frameA extends JFrame{
public frameA(){
//done some operations..
SwingWorker worker=new Worker();
       worker.execute();

}
public static void main(string[] args){
  new frameA();
}

}
```

and in worker class

```
class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {



public Worker() {
    super();


}

//Executed on the Event Dispatch Thread after the doInBackground method is finished
@Override
protected void done() {
    //want to dispose the frameA here..


}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    // some db queries
  new frameB().setVisible(true);  
  // call to frameb
}
```

Comment: The situation looks suspiciously like one where using a single frame and [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) would be more appropriate. Also note that you are breaking swing threading rules by modifying swing components outside the EDT both in `main()` and `doInBackground()`.

Comment: is it not possible to dispose the frameA.. coz its required in my app.. i cannot use tabbed window

Answer (score 3):

1. The `done()` method of the `SwingWorker` is  usually overridden to  display the  final result. Upon
   completion of  `doInBackground()` , the   `SwingWorker` automaticlly  invokes
   `done()` in the EDT. So put your frame's invisible and visible code in this function.
2. The `doInBackground()` is not meant to do any GUI rendering task. You can invoke  `publish(V)` from `doInBackground()` function  which in turn invokes The `process(V)` method to run inside the EDT and performing GUI rendering task.

So a sample solution would be:

```
class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

  JFrame frameA;

  public Worker(JFrame frameA) {
    this.frameA = frameA;

  }

  @Override
  protected void done() {
    frameA.dispose();
    new frameB().setVisible(true); 

  }
  //other code
}
```

Now, create you `SwingWorker` instance by passing the target frame to it's constructor: `new Worker(frame)`; For your context you probably could make use of `this`

However, you should not really design your application to be dependent on multiple `JFrame`. There are reasons for not to use multiple `JFrame` window. For more, see [**The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice/9554657#9554657). A general work around with use case where multiple frame would be needed is [**explained here.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911454/how-to-restart-a-java-application-launching-a-specific-class-of-my-application/19913118#19913118)